# I want to reinforce the exact difference between these two prepositions used in the same sentence

Tags: prepositions

I want to reinforce the exact difference between these two prepositions used in the same sentence.

> I'll go for a walk **in** the seaside.
>
> I'll go for a walk **at** the seaside.

Is it grammatically wrong to say that we can use both?

Answer (score 2):

There is no grammatical question here: it is simply one of usage.

*At the seaside* is idiomatic: *in the seaside* is not.

*Go for a walking* is not idiomatic: *go for a walk* is.

Comment: So, can't I use ''in''?

Comment: It's grammatical, and it would be understood. But it's not what a native speaker would say.

Comment: @Enzo If you use *in* people will notice and write it off as a non-native speaker error.

Comment: @enzo I'd say the most common preposition is **along** *the seaside* or **alongside** *the (beach / shore / sea)*. People don't normally go for a walk *at* the seaside either. (Although it's a lot more common than *in* the seaside, which is simply bizarre.) However, people do go for a *seaside walk*, which dispenses with a preposition altogether.

Comment: Walking 'in the seaside' would get your feet wet.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I suspect this may be a "versions of English" thing. In British English "at the seaside" is (or used to be) a very common expression, meaning "in a place that is by the sea, especially a holiday resort". It does not necessarily mean that you are on the beach, or in the sea. In that context, "along the seaside" makes no more sense than "in the seaside".

Comment: @ColinFine This must be similar to *a house on the water* which makes no literal sense (normally) but which is commonly used—at least in the US. (Along with *by the water* and *near the water*.) I'm reminded of how in UK English *at the weekend* is normal—but in US English it's odd. (In US English it's *on the weekend*, which I understand is odd in UK English.)